# Cordova Android app update / versioncode

Tags: android, cordova

I need to update my android App. For this the Google Play Store says it has to be an other version code. How can I update it? If I go into the androidmanifest.xml and set android:versionCode="1" to android:versionCode="2". It will return to 1 after I debug.

What is wrong?

Lukas

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to add that a in your `config.xml` file with `android-versionCode="X"` :

```
<widget id="com.example.app" version="1.1.0" android-versionCode="2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```